# How to authenticate users in a commercial environment without on-premises Windows Server equipment?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

So what I need is a remote/cloud Windows Server that I can connect to using RDP (or another remote connection program) where I can create users, groups, basically everything I could do with an on-premises Server instance. What I need though is to be able to setup all the office computers to authenticate through the cloud AD. I have no clue how to do this. I cannot have a Server running on-premises, period. Just need something where I can connect each computer to the remote domain/forest, hopefully using an IP to the server, and then have the employees be able to logon to any domain-connected PC using their credentials. Thank you for any and all answers! -Scott

Answer (score 0):

You need [Azure Active Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt168838.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  You can control everything with remote management in the way you have described.  Per the provided link, "Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) provides an easy way for businesses to manage identity and access, both in the cloud and on-premises."